# A Contact has many email and generating them as extra columns in a query

Tags: mysql

A contact has many emails.  What I would like is this:

```
contacts.id  | contacts.name   |  emails.address      |  "emails.address 2"  
  1             Sheldon Cooper      sheldon@gma.com         shelly@coop.com
```

What I get is:

```
contacts.id  | contacts.name   |  emails.address      
  1             Sheldon Cooper      sheldon@gma.com         
  1             Sheldon Cooper      shelly@coop.com
```

The query I use is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM contacts
LEFT JOIN emails
ON contacts.id=emails.contactsId
```

One to many relationship and generating them as extra columns in the query result.  I think I need to use group concat but can't seem to get my head round it.

```
SELECT    a.id, a.name,
GROUP_CONCAT(b.address ORDER BY b.id) AS "email addresses"
FROM      contacts a
LEFT JOIN emails b ON a.id = b.contactsId
GROUP BY  a.id,a.name
```

The above gives in one column all the addresses separated by commas.

Comment: Will there be a case count of email addresses per user differs?

Comment: No. My question is for the possibility of different count of email addresses per user. user1 with 2 addresses and user2 with 3 addreses.

Comment: yes, there maybe different number of address, it's one to many relation ship.

Comment: Then pivoting fails to get your expected output. There should be a fixed count of values in the base table to stretch as pivot columns.

Comment: If you dont have fixed number of addresses then its difficult to get it at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, (select group_concat(address) 
           from emails 
           where contacts.id=emails.contactsId) 
FROM contacts
```

Comment: right, single quotes around 'address' removed. Works fine now. And thanks for sqlfiddle discovery btw.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
select c.id, c.name, group_concat(g.address)
from contacts c inner join emails g
on c.id=g.contactsId
group by c.id
```

Comment: @trafalgar: you want it in separate column??